# Transcendence of $\log 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I am not number theorist, forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Recently I was curious about the ideas behind the transcendence of $\log 2$.

For the number $e$, It seems that the transcendence can be obtained by a argument of fast convergence of the Taylor expansion but the same ideas do not apply to $\log 2$. Talking with number theorists I got an explanation based on the results of Baker. Unfortunately this person can not point me towards a survey or a paper discussing the ideas behind this transcendence so I come here to ask:

*What are the ideas behind the transcendence of this number?*

Any text (paper,book, blog) suitable for non number theorists is also welcome as an answer.

Comment: An excellent source is the book "Making transcendence transparent: an intuitive approach to classical transcendental number theory". By Edward Burger and Robert Tubbs. Springer-Verlag (2004), ISBN: 978-0387214443.

Comment: you see this paper:http://www.math.ethz.ch/~fuchsc/fs10/dat-script12.pdf

Comment: An earlier book, "Irrational Numbers" by Ivan Niven, available in paperback from the M.A.A. now. Very nice, about half the book on transcendence.

Comment: Andre, Hashem adn Will thank you all for the references. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).  There is a sketch of a proof and several references at the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Qiaochu, thank you for the link and I think I should thank you for do not down vote this question. It is such a shame that I did not found for myself the answer in wikipedia. I fact, I looked there before post the question, but I was suggested to looking for Baker's Theorem and don't knew the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.